# I cannot cut the sides of my div element so that it fits the image and text inside

Tags: html

```
<div class = "container-fluid">
    <body style="background-color:#D3D3D3">  

     <h1 class="text-center">Nelson Mandela</h1>
     <h3 class = "text-center"><em>A man who believed in freedom</em><h3> 
     <br>

     <div style="background-color:gray" class="text-center">   
        <img class="img-responsive" style="margin:0px" src="https://b-i.forbesimg.com/mfonobongnsehe/files/2013/12/Mandela.jpg">
         <p style="font-size:15px">"Education is the most powerful weapon which you can use to change the world."</p>    
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: You can't have the body element as a child of a div

Comment: nor can you open a div and then not close it, but anyways, add `display:inline-block;` to the div's style. this may have some other undesired results.

Answer (score 0):

1st your `<body></body>` should be the container of all your HTML

2nd close your `<h3>` with `</h3>`

3rd add `display: inline-block;` to the div that contains the img and text will remove the extra space. (read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp)

4th add `text-align: center;` to the parent will center the child (make sure your parent container have a width)

```css
.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}

.centered{
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color:#D3D3D3">
  <div class="container-fluid centered">
    <h1 class="text-center">Nelson Mandela</h1>
    <h3 class="text-center"><em>A man who believed in freedom</em></h3>
    <br>

    <div style="background-color:gray" class="text-center inline-block">
      <img class="img-responsive" style="margin:0px" src="https://b-i.forbesimg.com/mfonobongnsehe/files/2013/12/Mandela.jpg">
      <p style="font-size:15px">"Education is the most powerful weapon which you can use to change the world."</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```